# Problemas com alarme android

Tags: android

A ideia é enviar uma notificação ao utilizador de 24 em 24 horas ao utilizador.

O utilizador tem uma lista e quando clica vai adicionar um alarme.

Caso o tempo da actualidade seja maior que o tempo do alarme vamos adicionar 24 horas para ele so repetir no proximo dia e não de imediato.

Até aqui tudo bem o problema surge quando o utilizador altera  a data para 1 dia atras.

Suponhamos :

**Dia 27 de janeiro**.

O utilizador quer um alarme para 12:30  todos os dia, caso o tempo actual seja maior que estas 12:30 só vai dar o alarme no **dia 28 janeiro**, caso o utilizador ande para trás com o calendário para o dia por exemplo 10 de janeiro só começa receber notificações novamente no dia 28 de janeiro.

Outro problema tambem é que se colocar o meu calendario para 1 dia aseguir e se o tempo for maior que o actual dispara de imediato o alarme.

Gostava de saber a vossa opinião e se é correcto setar um alarme dependente de um click do utilizador, pois ele apartir desse momento nunca mais é alterado e secalhar para resolver os erros acima deveria de ser alterado .

E se souberem uma solução para este problema ficaria agradecido.

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent;


    Intent intent = new Intent(HorariosActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    intent.putExtra("id", favId);

    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HorariosActivity.this, favId, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long agora = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    firstTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if (agora > firstTime) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
        firstTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) HorariosActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, 86100000, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Tiago, quando você refere ao utilizador alterar a data, você se refere a data do Android ou a data do alarme? Vamos pegar seu exemplo, quando você diz andar para trás na data 10 de janeiro, você quer dizer qual das duas?

Comment: Mudar a data do android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiago, você pode captar essas mudanças de data e hora através de um `Broadcast`, assim sempre que o usuário mudar o horário do dispositivo, você pode setar o alarme corretamente de acordo com a nova data.

**Algumas das ações que você pode interceptar são estas:**

[ACTION_TIME_TICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK)

[ACTION_TIME_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)

[ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)

Primeiro você tem que criar a sua classe `Broadcast` que será responsável por receber a ação:

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // Configure o alarme corretamente aqui
   }
}
```

Em segundo, devemos registrar no `Manifest` seu `Broadcast` e a ação que ele vai interceptar.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">

   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED">
       </action>
   </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Dentro do método `onReceive` você pode testar qual é a ação que você está recebendo através da `intent`, e assim efetuar a configuração correta do alarme.

---

Lendo alguns relatos, existe um bug que quando o usuário seta o tempo para trás, a notificação da ação só é enviada quando o relógio captar o próximo dia. Seria melhor você efetuar os testes para verificar se isso realmente acontece.

**Mais informações nestes links:**

[Android - Broadcast Receivers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)

[ACTION_TIME_CHANGED or ACTION_DATE_CHANGED, can't make them work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912885/action-time-changed-or-action-date-changed-cant-make-them-work)

Comment: So mais uma pergunta eu tenho multiplos alarmes vindos da base de dados de mysql para o meu android e queria saber se era possivel  a qualquer altura principalmente offline se o utilizador mudar as suas horas enviar as notificaçoes??